# Problem understanding shared_ptr

Tags: c++, reference, shared-ptr

I have a:

```
template<class K,class V>
struct Node
{
node_ptr parent_;//node_ptr is a shared_ptr<Node<K,V>>
node_ptr& get_parent()const
{
return parent_;
}
void set_parent(node_ptr& p)
{
parent_ = p;
}
//the get set for left and right are analogical
};
```

I cannot understand why this works:

```
auto zz = get_parent(get_parent(z));
rb_left_rotate(t,zz);
```

but this does not:

```
rb_left_rotate(t,get_parent(get_parent(z)));
```

by works I mean that inside rb_left_rotate I have:

```
template<class Tree_T, class Node_T>
void rb_left_rotate(Tree_T& t,Node_T& x)
{
    auto y = get_right(x);
    set_right(x,get_left(y));
    if (get_left(y))
    {
        set_parent(get_left(y),x);
    }
    auto tmp = get_parent(x);
    //y's current parrent is x
    set_parent(y,tmp);//by works I mean that this line WILL NOT set x to empty
......
}
```

Comment: I thought I had my crystal ball at hand, but I don't think it is able to see so far. You are presenting a class that has a member function `get_parent` that returns a reference to a shared pointer but you are then asking about a different code that uses a free function from which you do not state what is returned (my guess: the free function returns by value)

Answer (score 2):

`rb_left_rotate()` accepts `Node_T` as a reference to non-const. Such a reference can only be bound to an l-value, that is, a non-temporary object. `auto zz = get_parent(get_parent(z));` creates such an l-value named `zz`. In expression `rb_left_rotate(t,get_parent(get_parent(z)));`, on the other hand, the result of `get_parent(z)` is an r-value, i.e., a temporary value, which can not be bound to a reference to non-const.

This is not related to the fact that you are using a smart pointer.

Comment: The difference being (more or less)  l-values are references and things with names, and r-values are things returned from functions (unless by reference).

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between `Node` and `Node_T`?

How comes you declare `get_parent` as a no-parameter member function, but call it by passing a parameter?

The only thing that seems likely to modify `x` is the line:

```
set_right(x,get_left(y));
```

What does `set_right` do?

In general, you will probably get more predictable behaviour if you pass around `shared_ptr`s as true values, rather than references to `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Probably, what `get_parent(y)` does is just call `y->get_parent()`. It is an overload hook that can be overloaded for different types of `y`.

Comment: `Node_T` most likely can not be passed by value in that function since it is a node of the tree whose pointers must be reassigned.